# What is mean method Apply on Scala

Tags: scala

according to this link  [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm) 
and then im create code like this :

```
    object objPersamaan{
      def main(args : Array[String]){
        val x = objPersamaan("Budi ")
        println(x)
      }
      def apply(pX:String) = pX + "Belajar"
      def unapply(pZ:Int) : Option[Int] = if(pZ%2==0) Some(pZ/2) else None
    }
```

i can't still dont understand, how can **objPersamaan("Budi ")** would had value **Budi Belajar**? is that method **apply** like constructor with parameter? or what? can anyone, explain more detail why the process from method **apply**? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, you can omit the method name `apply`. So calling `objPersamaan("Budi ")` is the same as `objPersamaan.apply("Budi ")`, which then concatenates the String `Belajar` to the given parameter.

When you have an object and call it without a method name, just your arguments, the copmiler expands this call with `MyObject.apply(...)`. This comes from the fact, that you often use objects where you want to **apply** something to (e.g. in factories), so Scala built this feature directly into the language.

```
case class MyObj(foo: String, bar: String)
object MyObj {
  def apply(x: Int): MyObj = MyObj(x.toBinaryString, x.toHexString)
}

// ...
MyObj(42)
// same as
MyObj.apply(42)
```

Comment: ok thank you so much Martin
[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm)